# Add a segment that will always stay in Google Analytics' "Audience overview"

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

If you go in Google Analytics' `Audience overview`, you can `Add segment`:

[image]

Once done, click "Save". The new segment is now displayed:

[image]

Now close the browser, and open the browser again, `Audience overview`: the segment is no more there! You have to do `Add segment` once again manually!

**How to add a segment once for all that will stay in Google Analytics' `Audience overview`?**

Comment: Solution: shortcut (now called "Saved report" in new GA interface). [Disadvantage though](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Reports/Saved-Reports/td-p/1170553#).